# MapRoute not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Considering the mapped routes below, when the user goes to /Home, why would the second route be hitting instead of the first?  My assumption was that going to /Home would result in the first route being hit, but for some reason the second one is being used.

Why is this?

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
          "Home page behind auth",
          "Home",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "HomeSecure", id = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Default",                                              
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
        );
    }
```

edit: just to be clear, I want /Home to go to the HomeSecure action in the Home controller.

edit2:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AuthorizeHasAccess]
        public ActionResult HomeSecure()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Post the signatures of both HomeSecure() and Index()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information that you've given, I don't think that either route will match the request. MVC will be looking for method signatures with an "id" argument, and your action methods have none. If the request does in fact take you to the Index method on the Home controller, check to see if an error handler somewhere is trapping that condition and then redirecting you to /Home/Index

If you set the route table as follows, the first route will match as required.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Home page behind eRaider",
      url: "Home",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HomeSecure" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",                                              
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
}
```

Comment: I removed the id requirement from the first route, as you have in your example, and the second route is still hitting (as before).  I agree with you, however, I think your route should work too, but it doesn't.  Odd.

Comment: Is there any other code that might be redirecting the application to /Home/Index, rather than the route doing it? (just added something to my answer to that effect).